# Why does cygwin sha512 create different checksums depending on terminal?

Tags: cygwin, hashing, mingw

I'm using Windows 7 and have both Cygwin and the ming-based Git command line tool.

When I issue the command:

```
c:\>echo -n hello | e:\cygwin\bin\sha512sum
```

from the Windows cmd, it generates

```
91fe211053c6377ddfd218a061f96de1ca304b10d966a4c3572d9af22bbe86dc471653d0f9b14f923762d0bf83a0abfe285b855e1ee06b0d4ab4a60a8d8801e3 *-
```

which I believe to be **incorrect**.

However, when I issue the command

```
$ echo -n hello | /e/cygwin/bin/sha512sum
```

from the git command line, it generates

```
9b71d224bd62f3785d96d46ad3ea3d73319bfbc2890caadae2dff72519673ca72323c3d99ba5c11d7c7acc6e14b8c5da0c4663475c2e5c3adef46f73bcdec043 *-
```

which I believe is the correct hex checksum. I was assuming the exact same input is being sent to the exact same binary executable, but that can't be right with the behavior I'm seeing. Does Windows CMD do some kind of funny encoding that sends different input to the cygwin sha512 binary?

**EDIT**
For anyone interested in getting the right checksum from a standard Windows cmd prompt, the trick is not to use the window echo command (the answer alludes to this). Using cygwin's echo command generates the correct checksum.

E.g.,

```
e:\cygwin\bin\echo -n hello | e:\cygwin\bin\sha512sum
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default windows `echo` command adds spaces and line termination, even if called with `-n`. Try this: `echo -n hello > a.txt` followed by `dir`, and you'll see you don't have a 5 byte file.

Answer (score 3):

The default windows echo doesn't understand "-n".
So the two commands are not equivalent.

```
e:\cygwin64\bin>echo -n "hello" |od -c
0000000   -   n       "   h   e   l   l   o   "      \r  \n
0000015

$ echo -n "hello" |od -c
0000000   h   e   l   l   o
0000005
```